Vega charts draw ticks with values
I'm trying to draw multiple arcs chart in Vega.
Is it possible to draw lines with values on top of each arc? like on the attached image
Each line should go through all arcs and ends on top of the outer one (like on image).
I also need to show number that represents values on top of each line
Here is my charts config

Is this suitable?
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 600,
  "signals": [
    {"name": "centerX", "update": "width / 2"},
    {"name": "centerY", "update": "height / 2"},
    {"name": "radiusRef", "update": "min(width / 2, height / 2)"},
    {"name": "padding", "value": 18},
    {"name": "numArcs", "value": 2},
    {"name": "arcStep", "update": "0.4 / numArcs"},
    {"name": "ticksNumber", "value": 6},
    {"name": "ticksColor", "value": "#000000"},
    {"name": "showTicks", "value": true},
    {"name": "arc1", "value": {"value": 70, "fillColor": "#77A7FB"}},
    {"name": "arc2", "value": {"value": 40, "fillColor": "#FFB677"}},
    {"name": "innerRadius1", "update": "radiusRef * (1 - arcStep)"},
    {"name": "outerRadius1", "update": "radiusRef * 1 - padding"},
    {"name": "mainValue3", "value": 80},
    {"name": "minValue", "value": 0},
    {"name": "maxValue", "value": 100},
    {"name": "fontFactor", "update": "(radiusRef / 5) / 25"},
    {"name": "backgroundColor", "value": "#cbd1d6"},
    {"name": "fillColor3", "value": "#77FF77"}
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "ticks",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "sequence",
          "as": "data",
          "start": {"signal": "0"},
          "stop": {"signal": "(maxValue - minValue) + 0.1"},
          "step": {"signal": "(maxValue - minValue) / (ticksNumber - 1)"}
        },
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.data + minValue", "as": "data_2"},
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "radianRef",
          "expr": "PI * (datum.data / (maxValue - minValue))"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "x",
          "expr": "centerX - ((outerRadius1 - (outerRadius1 - innerRadius1) * 0.6) * cos(datum.radianRef))"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "y",
          "expr": "centerY - ((outerRadius1 - (outerRadius1 - innerRadius1) * 0.7) * sin(datum.radianRef))"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "mainValues",
      "values": [
        {"name": "Policy 1", "value": 27},
        {"name": "Policy 2", "value": 43}
      ],
      "transform": [{"type": "window", "ops": ["row_number"], "as": ["index"]}]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "gaugeScale",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {"data": "ticks", "field": "data_2"},
      "zero": false,
      "range": {"signal": "[-PI / 2, PI / 2]"}
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "mainValues", "field": "name"},
      "range": {"scheme": "category10"}
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "arc",
      "name": "gauge3",
      "from": {"data": "mainValues"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"signal": "centerX"},
          "y": {"signal": "centerY"},
          "startAngle": {"signal": "-PI / 2"},
          "endAngle": {"signal": "PI / 2"},
          "outerRadius": {
            "signal": "radiusRef * (1 - datum.index * arcStep) - padding"
          },
          "innerRadius": {
            "signal": "radiusRef * (1 - datum.index * arcStep) + padding"
          },
          "fill": {"signal": "backgroundColor"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "arc",
      "from": {"data": "mainValues"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {"startAngle": {"signal": "-PI / 2"}},
        "update": {
          "x": {"signal": "centerX"},
          "y": {"signal": "centerY"},
          "innerRadius": {
            "signal": "radiusRef * (1 - datum.index * arcStep) + padding"
          },
          "outerRadius": {
            "signal": "radiusRef * (1 - datum.index * arcStep) - padding"
          },
          "endAngle": {"scale": "gaugeScale", "field": "value"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "name"}
        }
      }
    },
        {
      "type": "arc",
      "from": {"data": "mainValues"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {"startAngle": {"signal": "-PI / 2"}},
        "update": {
          "x": {"signal": "centerX"},
          "y": {"signal": "centerY"},
          "innerRadius": {
            "signal": "radiusRef * (1 - datum.index * arcStep) + padding"
          },
          "outerRadius": {
            "signal": "radiusRef * (1 - 1 * arcStep) - padding+50"
          },
          "startAngle": {"scale": "gaugeScale", "signal": "datum.value-1"},
          "endAngle": {"scale": "gaugeScale", "field": "value"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "name"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}



It's kinda what I needed. Thank you!
Is it possible to add numbers with values on top of each line also?

Yes but please keep each question to one problem. Ask another question if you still need help. Thanks

Okay, I've created separate question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78861535/draw-text-with-values-on-vega-chart
Thanks!
